# Unable to access the ArcGIS JavaScript application in local host

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

My organisation has multiple ArcGIS JS API (3.13) applications. Those are working fine and good. I am new to GIS technology and I want to add more features to the applications which are already developed. I want to copy those applications in my local wamp server and do changes in my local system (localhost).

I tried to do that but I am unable to load the Dojo scripts in my localhost.

My question is: Do I need to install the ArcGIS JS API in my localhost or how to make it work in local system as it working on air?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. The JavaScript API can be accessed locally, from a central server, or from the Internet, depending on how you have configured it. Please [Edit] the question to describe what you have attempted and what specific error you encountered.

Comment: Do you have an ArcGIS server instance? If yes, are there map services published to it? If yes, is there a web adaptor installed?

Comment: Ya it is installed... then what to do ...

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to install ArcGIS API for Javascript on your localhost.  The most common way to access it is from the CDN.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.25/esri/css/esri.css">
<script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.25/"></script>
```

See https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jshelp/intro_accessapi.html